# how to calculate in the barstate.islast and label the chart

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to do calculation on candles and have to calculate them in the last bar and save them into an array, but after that I want to label those information from array into chart, however I can't label in the if barstate.islast , because it just label the last candle, is there any way to calculate in the barstate.islast and then label array information into the chart ?

Comment: Please provide some of your code, so we can see your issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.